# Перемещение папки из одного репозитория в другой

Tags: git, github

У меня вопрос:

Изначально у меня был один репозиторий в аккаунте на github - `spasalon-mvc.git`

Потом я создал еще один - `testJavaGit.git`

Набрал в `git bash` следующие строки:

```
cd testJavaGit ( моя локальная папка, тут все нормально )
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git://github.com:EVOSandru6/spasalon-mvc.git ( тут я перепутал название репозитория !!! )
git push origin master ( ввел данные от кабинета, вошел )
git add .
git commit -m "more changes to index"
git push origin master
```

Как теперь удалить файлы из репозитория "spasalon-mvc.git" и связать папку testJavaGit с репозиторием testJavaGit.git

Пробовал проделать все действия выше повторно, но только со строкой

```
git://github.com:EVOSandru6/testJavaGit.git
```

Вместо

```
git://github.com:EVOSandru6/spasalon-mvc.git
```

Но пишет ругательство `remote origin already exist`

Что делать?

Comment: Создать свой вопрос отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Вначале выполняете

```
git remote rm origin
```

этим удалите привязку. Потом привязываете по новому

```
git remote add origin git://github.com:EVOSandru6/testJavaGit.git
```

дальше пушите

```
git checkout master
git push origin master
```

а старый репозиторий просто удаляете из github.